# Show by contradiction that a martingale converge to zero almost surely.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

> Theorem 5.2.9. If $X_n \geq 0$ is a supermartingale then as $n \rightarrow \infty, X_n \rightarrow X$ a.s. and $E X \leq E X_0$

> 5.2.9. Let $Y_1, Y_2, \ldots$ be nonnegative i.i.d. random variables with $E Y_m=1$ and $P\left(Y_m=1\right)<1$.
>
> - (i) Show that $X_n=\prod_{m \leq n} Y_m$ defines a martingale.
> - (ii) Use Theorem $5.2 .9$ and an argument by contradiction to show $X_n
>      \rightarrow 0$ a.s.

I am trying to show that $X_n \to 0$ a.s., and I want to try to contradict the fact that $X_n$ is a martingale and must not be a supermartingale by showing the inequality is actually strict. To contradict the statement, my idea is to assume there exists a set $A$ of positive probability on which $\lim X_n $ does not converge to zero, and derive the contradiction from this. However, all I would obtain is $0<E[X]\leq E[X_0]$ however $E[X_0]=E[Y_1]=1$ which I am having trouble realizing as a contradcition.

Thank you

Comment: Perhaps you can first show there must be an $\epsilon>0$ such that $P[Y_n\geq 1+\epsilon] > 0$. Then if that happens on step $n+1$ we get $X_{n+1}\geq X_n(1+\epsilon)$.

Comment: @Michael Does this proof hold up? Assume that $\forall \epsilon > 0, Y_n  < 1+\epsilon$  a.s.. Then $E[Y_n]< 1+\epsilon$. Taking $\epsilon \to 0$, we obtain that $E[Y_n]<1$ which is a contradiction. Therefore, it must be that there exists some $\epsilon > 0$ such that $P(Y_n \geq 1 + \epsilon) > 0$.

Comment: If $E[Y_1]<1+\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$, at most you can say that $E[Y_1]\leq 1$. So I don't think your argument yet reaches $E[Y_1]<1$. However you can say $\{Y_1\geq 1+1/k\}\searrow \{Y_1>1\}$ (as $k\rightarrow\infty$) so by continuity of probability we get $P[Y_1>1]=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} P[Y_1>1+1/k]$. There is also a nice fact that if $Z\geq 0$ almost surely and $E[Z]=0$ then $Z=0$ almost surely.

Comment: I meant $\{Y_1\geq 1+1/k\}\nearrow \{Y_1>1\}$.

Answer (score 4):

The idea given by Michael in the comment is very good : $\mathbb P(Y_1>1)$ is positive. Otherwise, since $\mathbb E[Y_1]=1$ and $Y_1\leqslant 1$, this would force $Y_1=1$ almost surely which contradicts $\mathbb P(Y_m=1)<1$. Since $\{Y_1>1\}=\bigcup_{k\geqslant 1}\{Y_1>1+1/k\}$ and $(\{Y_1>1+1/k\})_{k\geqslant 1}$ is non-decreasing, one get that for some $k_0\geqslant 1$,
$
\mathbb P(Y_1>1+1/k_0)>0.
$

By the second Borel-Cantelli lemma, we infer that for almost every $\omega$, there exists an increasing sequence of integers $\left(m_{j}(\omega)\right)_{j\geqslant 1}$ such that for each $j\geqslant 1$, $ Y_{m_{j}(\omega)}(\omega)>1+1/k_0$.
As a consequence, one has
$$
X_{m_{j}(\omega) }(\omega)=X_{m_{j}(\omega)-1 }(\omega)Y_{m_{j}(\omega)}(\omega)
\geqslant X_{m_{j}(\omega)-1 }(\omega)\left(1+\frac 1{k_0}\right)
$$

By Theorem 5.2.9., we know that $X_{m_{j}(\omega) }(\omega)\to X(\omega)$ and
$X_{m_{j}(\omega)-1 }(\omega)\to X(\omega)$ hence taking the limit in (1) gives $X(\omega)\geqslant X(\omega)\left(1+\frac 1{k_0}\right)$ hence $X(\omega)=0$.

Comment: @Michael Thanks again!